# PowerShell, RegEx: Optional Entries - how?

Tags: regex, powershell

How can I detect in a line optional fields?

```
    $l = "prg=PowerShell°V=2.0°dtd=20120602°user=kjuz°pwd=jhiuz°chk=876876°dep=Lab1°floor=4°"
    $found = $l -match '(?=.*?°dtd=(\d+))(?=.*?°user=(.+?)°)(?=.*?°chk=(.+?)°).*'
```

All the fileds in -match must exist otherwise $found = $false.
How can I detect optional fields like >dep=Lab1< and >floor=4< that may be there and then I would need their values?
Is there a 'one-line' solution again the order of the fields varies, is not fix?

Thanks in advance
Gooly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about divide and conquer approach instead? Spit the string, the `°` character seems like a field separator. That is,

```
$ll = $l.Split('°')
```

Now you got another an array that can be filtered with `-match` operator like so,

```
$ll -match "(floor)|(user)"
# Output:
user=kjuz
floor=4
```

By filtering the splitted string, you can quite easily work forward without complex and hard to maintain regex that tries to match the whole pattern on one bite.